# Loop with Dice rolling program, previous roll and double check

Tags: java, dice

A fairly trivial problem to most I am sure but I can't quite work out how I'm meant to get the previous dice integer to remain the same as the previous roll of die in the program. I think the code is fairly self explanatory and this is such a trivial program I'm kicking myself for not being able to get my head around it.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int min = 1;
        int max = 6;
        int loop = 0;
        int diceRollOne = 0;
        int diceRollTwo = 0;
        int diceTotal = 0;
        int prevDiceTotal = 0;

        while (loop < 15000) {
            loop++;
            diceRollOne = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            diceRollTwo = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            diceTotal = diceRollOne + diceRollTwo;

            System.out.println("Dice Roll 1: " + diceRollOne);
            System.out.println("Dice Roll 2: " + diceRollTwo);
            System.out.println("Dice Total: " + diceTotal);
            System.out.println("previous total: " + prevDiceTotal);

            prevDiceTotal = diceTotal;

            if (diceRollOne == diceRollTwo || diceTotal == prevDiceTotal) {
                System.out.println("After " + loop + " loops the");
                System.out.println("Numbers Match, YOU GET NOTHING, YOU LOSE, GOOD DAY SIR!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea being 15,000 simulations. Roll two dice. If you roll a double quit. If you roll the same sum in the current roll as the sum of the previous roll then quit. I've tried debugging by printing out the previous dice total but it defaults to zero every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to move the `prevDiceTotal = diceTotal;` to after your if statement.

```
        if (diceRollOne == diceRollTwo || diceTotal == prevDiceTotal) {
            System.out.println("After " + loop + " loops the");
            System.out.println("Numbers Match, YOU GET NOTHING, YOU LOSE, GOOD DAY SIR!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        prevDiceTotal = diceTotal;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although my System.out.println still tells me that the value of prevDiceTotal is 0.

Comment: Only for the first pass through (where it should be zero or some other number that represents it wasn't set at this time). If it loops more than once, the value is correct

Comment: Even after looping it maintains the value of 0. The value never changes. This also means that diceTotal and prevDiceTotal can never be the same so the loop will only quit because of a double.

Comment: My apologies, I had accidently inlcuded the prevDiceTotal = diceTotal; in the if loop by accident. I am ashamed.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following:

```
prevDiceTotal = diceTotal;

if(diceRollOne == diceRollTwo || diceTotal == prevDiceTotal){
```

As it's written now it guarantees `if-expression` to be **True**.

Move the assignment **after** your `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a good IDE can help you.  Here is what IntelliJ IDEA (which has a free [Community Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html)) shows for your code.  Note the highlighting of the `if()` statement along with a description of the problem.

[image: IntelliJ Screenshot]

As others have said, move the assignment of `prevDiceTotal` after the `if()` block to solve the problem.